# Razor Pages Model Binding in Partial View after post form

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I trying to achieve to following: let's say I have a Create VM form. This is all very standard with stuff:

Model

```
[BindProperty]
public NewVM NewVM { get; set; }
```

NewVM Model (part of):

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int SelectedTemplateId { get; set; }
public List<Templates> Templates { get; set; }
```

Template Model (part of):

```
public int Id{ get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Form (part of)

```
<form method="post">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="vmname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Virtual Machine Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm">
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

A part of the Create VM form is selecting a template. This is dependent of the Cluster selected. This a presented as a dropdown box

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Cluster</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(x => Model.ClusterId, new SelectList(Model.Clusters, "Id", "Name"), "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", id = "clusters" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Tenant.ClusterId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

So far so good. When a cluster is selected the following Ajax call is made to retrieve the templates available for that cluster:

Javascript:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#clusters").change(function () {

                var host = $(this).val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/VM/AddVmDC2?handler=GetTemplates",
                    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("XSRF-TOKEN",
                            $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
                    },
                    data: { "host": host },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#templatebody").html(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Backend

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGetTemplates(int clusterid)
        {
            _apilocation = _config["apiurl"];

            var templates = await helper.QueryApi(_apilocation, "/api/inventory/template?clusterid=" + clusterid);
            NewVM.Templates = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Templates>>(templates);

            return Partial("_Templates", Tenant);
        }
```

Partial View

```
@model NewVM

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedTemplateId , new SelectList(Model.Templates, "Id", "Name"), "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control form-control-sm", id = "templates" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.SelectedTemplateId , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Partial view is called in Form

```
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Templates</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8" id="templatebody">
                @{
                    <partial name="_Templates" for="NewVM"/>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem is that when I post the form SelectedTemplateId is always null. What am I doing wrong here. Can someone help me explain why SelectedTemplateId is always null.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You ajax data is

```
data: { "host": host },
```

and your handler is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGetTemplates(int clusterid)
```

you need to change `int clusterid` to `int host`,so that you can get the data in ajax.

And if your SelectedTemplateId  is still null,can you share your Tenant structure,and check  the SelectedTemplateId  in it.